# SOLR Graph Traversal using Multi-Value fields

Tags: graph, solr, streaming

Trying graph traversal on my collection with multi value fields. Result from a simple search expression like this

search(mycollection,q="pscnav:Magazines", qt="/select",fl="pscnav,connamenav",sort="connamenav asc")

may be as below.

```
{
  "result-set": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "connamenav": [
          "Marco Lambert",
          "Alan Harding"
        ],
        "pscnav": [
          "Magazines"
        ]
      },
      {
        "connamenav": [
          "Alfred Mitchell",
          "Raquel Schultz"
        ],
        "pscnav": [
          "Magazines"
        ]
      },                
      {
        "connamenav": [
          "Audra Young"
        ],
        "pscnav": [
          "Magazines",
          "Third Party Debt Collection",
          "Credit Information Furnishers"
        ]
      },      
      {
        "EOF": true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME": 17
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to do a graph traversal on this result. But as fields in this result have multiple values the nodes expression does not work. So I wrap this search result within cartesianProduct expression as below.

cartesianProduct(search(mycollection,q="pscnav:Magazines", qt="/select",fl="pscnav,connamenav",sort="connamenav asc"),pscnav,connamenav)

That flattens all tuples with single value each. The outcome is as below for the

```
{
  "result-set": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "connamenav": "Marco Lambert",
        "pscnav": "Magazines"
      },
      {
        "connamenav": "Alan Harding",
        "pscnav": "Magazines"
      },
      {
        "connamenav": "Alfred Mitchell",
        "pscnav": "Magazines"
      },
      {
        "connamenav": "Raquel Schultz",
        "pscnav": "Magazines"
      },      
      {
        "connamenav": "Audra Young",
        "pscnav": "Magazines"
      },
      {
        "connamenav": "Audra Young",
        "pscnav": "Third Party Debt Collection"
      },
      {
        "connamenav": "Audra Young",
        "pscnav": "Credit Information Furnishers"
      },
      {
        "EOF": true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME": 16
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Next I wanted to traverse on this result set using nodes expression. Using this expression below

nodes(cartesianProduct(search(mycollection,q="pscnav:Magazines", qt="/select",fl="pscnav,connamenav",sort="connamenav asc"),pscnav,connamenav), walk="Magazines->pscnav", gather="connamenav")

It throws exception - java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Slices not found for cartesianProduct(search(mycollection,q="pscnav:Magazines",qt="/select",fl="pscnav,connamenav",sort="connamenav asc"),pscnav,connamenav)

Alternately if I use this version of the nodes expression -

nodes(mycollection,cartesianProduct(search(mycollection,q="pscnav:Magazines", qt="/select",fl="pscnav,connamenav",sort="connamenav asc"),pscnav,connamenav), walk="pscnav->pscnav", gather="connamenav")

It throws an exception "null:java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type SORTED_SET for field 'connamenav' (expected=SORTED). Re-index with correct docvalues type"

Any suggestion, what I am doing wrong here? Reindexing the outcome of the cartesianProduct to a separate solr collection is not really an option for me. Looking for a query time solution.

Any pointer would be really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest posting this to `solr-user` to get more eyeballs on it, in particular for slightly more low level experience with streaming expressions. Make sure to add any answers you get as answers here as well.

Comment: Did that as well. Hoping to get some answer.